# iDrac 8 how to unmount virtual CD after enterprise evaluation ran out?

Tags: dell, drac

I have a Dell R230. I used the iDrac8 Enterprise Evaluation License to mount the Windows server iso for installation (it's larger than a regular DVD). Now the Enterprise Evaluation License has run out and the menu where I could mount the iso is no longer accessible but the iso is still mounted as virtual Disc.

How can I unmount it without an Enterprise license?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the idrac, not the server. This [document](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/poweredge-fx2/idrac8_2.30.30.30_ug/restarting-idrac?guid=guid-19072daf-59b6-42cd-af8f-2467c33ea25e&lang=en-us) lists all things iDrac 7/8.

**Restarting iDRAC**

You can perform a hard or soft iDRAC restart without turning off the server:

- Hard restart — On the server, press and hold the LED button for 15 seconds.
- Soft restart — Using iDRAC Web interface or RACADM.